# How to match a string from one column to another string in other column in Python?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a password column for users:

```
 user_name       password   first_name  last_name  uses_name
 vance.jennings  vance      vance       jennings   true
 bino.lapsi      dflkjdk    bino        lapsi      false
```

I have filled the uses_name manually here but generally I need to check if first or last name of the user `==` password.

Please advise how can I do this?

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
users['uses_name'] = (users['password'].isin(users['first_name']) | 
                     users['password'].isin(users['last_name']))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need compare columns and chain conditions by `|` for `OR`:

```
users['uses_name'] = (users['last_name'] == users['password'])|
                     (users['first_name'] == users['password'])
```

Or compare both columns with [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) and get at least one `True` by [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
users['uses_name'] = users[['first_name', 'last_name']].eq(users['password'], axis=0).any(axis=1)
```

---

```
print (users)
        user_name password first_name last_name  uses_name
0  vance.jennings    vance      vance  jennings       True
1      bino.lapsi  dflkjdk       bino     lapsi      False
```

Comment: Bravo the second one seems to me very easy, wasn't familiar with such solution, you've taught me something new, thanks a lot!!!

Comment: why `eq(users['password'], 0)` 0 in this ?

Comment: This is `axis=0`.

Answer (score 0):

Another option using `pd.DataFrame.apply()` :

```
users.apply(lambda s: s['password'] == s['first_name'] or s['password'] == s['last_name'], axis=1)
```